# Inversion pair of $(123456)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

I have this exercise:

Let $h=(12)(34)(56)$ belonging to $S_6$ and let $H=\langle h\rangle$ be the subgroup.
Let $g=(123456)$

And then I have to find the pairs of inversions.

I understand inversions as those numbers that needs to be replaced to be in order. Since there is no numbers in $h# that are out of order, I would say there's no inversions.

However the solution says $I_h=\{(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)\}$

So I know I'm wrong 'cause obviously there are inversions.
So how would I find the pairs of inversions instead?

Comment: In two-line notation $(12)(34)(56) = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\2&1&4&3&6&5\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I don't understand what the permutation $g$ has to do with the question.

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with this part of the exercise, I just wanted to put all the information there